# How do i fix inserting to database with Sequelize Node Express Mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a simple registration form which i will then proceed to other CRUD operations new to node js

I have created the mysql database and done the modelling and connection with Sequelize also i have created my view with pug and i did console.log for the entries from my form and everything is fine till it gets to database insert

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var db = require('../src/database/connection');
var User = require('../src/model/User');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  res.render('signup');
});
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
    let { username, useremail, pass, re_pass } = req.body;

    let errors = [];

    //checking feilds 
    if( !username || !useremail || !pass || !re_pass)
    {
        errors.push({msg: 'Please no field should be left empty'});
    }
    //checking Password
    if(pass !== re_pass)
    {
        errors.push({msg: 'Passwords Dont Match'});
    }
    //check Password Length
    if(pass.length < 7)
    {
        errors.push({msg: 'Passwords should be more than 7 characters '})
    }

    //reload page with contents if error encountered
    if(errors.length > 0)
    {
        res.render('signup', {
            errors,
            username,
            useremail,
            pass,
            re_pass
        });
    } else{
        console.log(req.body);
        User.create({
        username,
        useremail,
        pass,
        }).then(user => res.redirect('/register')).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

This is the error i am getting. PLEASE HELP

```
{ SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: User.email cannot be null,
notNull Violation: User.password cannot be null
    at Promise.all.then (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:74:15)
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
    at Promise._fulfill (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
    at PromiseArray._resolve (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise_array.js:126:19)
    at PromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise_array.js:144:14)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:26)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\Node\waiyu\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
  name: 'SequelizeValidationError',
  errors:
   [ ValidationErrorItem {
       message: 'User.email cannot be null',
       type: 'notNull Violation',
       path: 'email',
       value: null,
       origin: 'CORE',
       instance: [User],
       validatorKey: 'is_null',
       validatorName: null,
       validatorArgs: [] },
     ValidationErrorItem {
       message: 'User.password cannot be null',
       type: 'notNull Violation',
       path: 'password',
       value: null,
       origin: 'CORE',
       instance: [User],
       validatorKey: 'is_null',
       validatorName: null,
       validatorArgs: [] } ] }
```

Comment: Can you show `../src/model/User.js`? And what is the output of `console.log(req.body);`?

Comment: ```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../database/connection');
module.exports = sequelize.define("User",
{
   id:{
       type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
       allowNull: false,
       autoIncrement: true,
       primaryKey: true
   },
   username: 
   {
       type: Sequelize.STRING(35),
       allowNull: false,
       unique: true
   },
   email:
   {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull:false,
        unique:true
   },
   password:
   {
       type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
       allowNull: false
   }
});
```

Comment: this is my model/user,js

Comment: req.body is showing the entries from the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that tried helping me solve this problem so my mistake was that i didnt point to the database rows in the create method so what i did was

```
User.create({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.useremail,
        password: req.body.pass,
        }).then(user => res.redirect('signup/register')).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

not

```
User.create({
        username,
        useremail,
        pass,
        }).then(user => res.redirect('/register')).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `req.body` is always empty
use [body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) to put request body to `req.body`

```
const express = require('express'),
      app = express(),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: This is added to app.js already or u suggest i add it to the signup.js ?